# Overriding case class methods and companion object methods using 1 trait?

Tags: scala, traits

given the following requirement:  I would like to inject code into a class and into the companion object at the same time.

The reason is database functionality : A delete method should be on instance level, while a find method should be situated in the companion object.

I'm wondering if such thing is possible using 1 trait? Or do is there some fundamental design flaw in my logic?

with best regards,

Stefan